# HTML anchor link - href and onclick both?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I want to author an anchor tag that executes some JavaScript and then proceeds to go wherever the `href` was taking it. Invoking a function that executes my JavaScript and then sets `window.location` or `top.location` to the `href` location doesn't work for me.

So, imagine I have an element with id "Foo" on the page. I want to author an anchor similar to:

```
<a href="#Foo" onclick="runMyFunction(); return false;">Do it!</a>
```

When this is clicked, I want to execute runMyFunction and then jump the page to `#Foo` (not cause a reload - using `top.location` would cause it to reload the page).

Suggestions? I am happy to use jQuery if it can help here...

Comment: `return true;` is the solution, but you can also call `location.hash = '#Foo'`. It will not reload the page.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Just `return true` instead?

The return value from the `onClick` code is what determines whether the link's inherent clicked action is processed or not - returning `false` means that it isn't processed, but if you return `true` then the browser will proceed to process it after your function returns and go to the proper anchor.

Comment: What if onclick doesn't return anything?

Comment: @maciek then the return value is treated as `undefined` which is considered false for these purposes.

Comment: In the past whenever I'd use use a js function to launch a new page, and put just a "#" for the href attribute, I'd return "-1" to prevent the default action, which is usually the browser jumping tot he top of the page, or sometimes I'd just not return anything. Lately I've had to revise all those pages as @Amber advised... to specifically return false, if I don't want the page to jump.

Comment: @Amber seems like if onclick doesn't return anything, the link's inherent clicked action will be processed.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use event.preventDefault() on click event handler.

Comment: @Ruben could you please explain why you shouldn't use event.preventDefault() on click event handler?

Answer (score 42):

```
<a href="#Foo" onclick="return runMyFunction();">Do it!</a>
```

and

```
function runMyFunction() {
  //code
  return true;
}
```

This way you will have youf function executed AND you will follow the link AND you will follow the link exactly after your function was successfully run.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if your function returns true after a deferred function call?

Comment: This doesn't work if I click "Open link in new tab"

Answer (score 7):

If the link should only change the location if the function run is successful, then do `onclick="return runMyFunction();"` and in the function you would return true or false.

If you just want to run the function, and then let the anchor tag do its job, simply remove the `return false` statement.

As a side note, you should probably use an event handler instead, as inline JS isn't a very optimal way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a clean HTML Structure, you can do this.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('link_1')
element.onClick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open('_top', element.getAttribute('href'))
}
```

Using jQuery

```js
$('a#link_1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const a = e.target
    window.open('_top', a.getAttribute('href'))
})
```

Comment: you putting spaces around everything that you can but not after `//` is really funny to me

Comment: I'm sorry about my poor syntax, I fixed it so that it follows current javascript standard.