# Html anchor tag onclick() and href execute simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, onclick

Similar to [HTML anchor link - href and onclick both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346043/html-anchor-link-href-and-onclick-both) post, mine is:

```
<a href="/tmp/download.mp3" onclick="update();">Download link</a>
```

The `update()` method would send another HTTP GET method to the server to update the which file has been downloaded and update the database. From the HTML code, there are 2 GET requests being triggered together and only ONE will get the response (the href download response) from the server. The `update()` is not being executed. Is there any method that i can get both GET methods to be executed? Javascript and Jquery suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: I think you're going to have to break up the functionality. I'd recommend getting rid of the href and have the update() call write to the database then pop a window to download the file.

Comment: you could work with a delay in your update() function, use a setTimeout(function(){})

Comment: First `click` and then `href`. Its a default behaviour

Comment: @johnSmith that's exactly what i am doing at this moment. But this is not a consistent solution as sometimes the timeout function is not called

Comment: Can you include the code for your `update` function?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the method will update the page by retrieving data from server via http get method. Pardon me that it includes some sensitive data that i choosed not to disclose. It will have 2 request being fired at the same time and only 1 get response if check from chrome development tool

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Forget about the `href` and just do it all in the click function. You can navigate to another page after the update is complete. Here is my JQuery suggestion:

HTML

```
<a id="download" href="/tmp/download.mp3">Download link</a>
```

JavaScript (with JQuery)

```
$("#download").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//this will prevent the link trying to navigate to another page
    var href = $(this).attr("href");//get the href so we can navigate later

    //do the update

    //when update has finished, navigate to the other page
    window.location = href;
});
```

NOTE: I added in an `id` for the `a` tag to ensure it can be selected accurately via JQuery

Comment: I'd leave the `href` as it was previously, then use `this.href` to update `window.location` in the event handler. If there are multiple download links per page (quite possible) then it's easier to switch to using a class, rather than ID selector, and also allows (partial) functionality for anybody who doesn't have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Although, if the `update` code is done with a callback then `this` may lose its original meaning: I will update again

Comment: Didn't work for me. Just work without `e.preventDefault();` line.