# Both onclick and href redirect in anchor tag

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-analytics, onclick, anchor

I have the following in my Wordpress page.php template:

```
<a role="button" onclick="<?php echo $link['analytics']; ?>" href="<?php echo $link['link']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" class="btn btn-large btn-<?php echo $link['color']; ?>">
                                    <i class="icon-white icon-<?php echo $link['icon']; ?>"></i> 
                                    <?php echo $link['link_text']; ?>
                                </a>
```

The resulting source code looks like this:

```
<a role="button" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', ‘itunes')" href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rescue-field-guide/id426955029?mt=8&ls=1" target="_blank" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
                                    <i class="icon-white icon-download"></i> 
                                    Download from the App Store                                    </a> 



<a role="button" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'google-play’)" href="https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cmc_rescue.rescue_field_guide&feature=search_result" target="_blank" class="btn btn-large btn-success">
                                    <i class="icon-white icon-download"></i> 
                                    Download from Google Play                                        </a>
```

The links appear like buttons due to the styling which is what I want and they successfully redirect to their respective pages, but they *don't* register as clicks in my GA account.

How can I get both parts of this functionality working; redirect and onclick?

From my review of these other questions:

[Html anchor tag onclick() and href execute simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250645/html-anchor-tag-onclick-and-href-execute-simultaneously)

[HTML anchor link - href and onclick both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346043/html-anchor-link-href-and-onclick-both)

it appears there may be a variety of ways to go about this. What is the simplest way to accomplish this for my scenario? Can I do this without using a separate javascript function or is there an issue with my google analytics function?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's copy-paste error, but the single quotes that are using need to all be the straight kind. Looks like you have different kinds around 'iTunes' and 'google-play'.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing this, but in my code the single quotes are okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because `ga` submits events asynchronously. Since in your scenario, a new page is loaded immediately afterwards, the events will be lost. Here is a discussion about how to make this work properly:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/24/outbound-link-tracking.html

Comment: Based on this information, I changed my approach and placed a jquery script in the <head> section '<script>
$(function() {
  $("a.tracked").click(function(e) {
    if (!ga.q) {
      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
        function () {
          document.location = url;
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
</script>'

Comment: Then in my page.php, I put a css class called "tracked" in the <a> tag. '<a role="button" href="<?php echo $link['link']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" class="tracked btn btn-large btn-<?php echo $link['color']; ?>">
                                        <i class="icon-white icon-<?php echo $link['icon']; ?>"></i> 
                                        <?php echo $link['link_text']; ?>
                                    </a> ' I still can't see any of the clicks in Google Analytics. I'm not sure if I set the goal up properly or if my code isn't working, ideas?

Comment: The first thing would be to check if the code generates a request to GA, e.g. using Chrome's Developer Tools.

Comment: Okay, everything was working just fine with the jquery implementation, I was looking in the wrong location in the GA account.  Thanks so much for your help! I would vote up your answer, but StackOverflow won't allow me until I increase my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked after reading the [link](http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/24/outbound-link-tracking.html) Andreas sent, thank you!

I changed my approach and placed a jquery script in the head section:

```
<script> 
$(function() { $("a.tracked").click(function(e) 
{ if (!ga.q) { var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback': 
function () { document.location = url; } }); 
e.preventDefault(); } }); }); 
</script>
```

Then in my page.php, I put a css class called "tracked" in the  tag.

```
<a role="button" href="<?php echo $link['link']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" class="tracked btn btn-large btn-<?php echo $link['color']; ?>"> 
<i class="icon-white icon-<?php echo $link['icon']; ?>"></i> 
<?php echo $link['link_text']; ?>
</a>
```