# New Page before Onclick function is called

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I'm essentially making jepoardy and trying to store a temporary variable using the inner, however when the user clicks the button, it takes them to the next page before the onclick function can be called. I've tried putting the onclick function inside the  tag, but it still doesn't work.

```
<a href="Easy.html"><button type="button"  onclick="categoryOnClick() "id="answer0" class="buttonquestion">200</button></a>  

var tempscore = 0;
var currentscore = 0;

function categoryOnClick(){
    tempscore = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: do you know what clicking on an `<a>` tag does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html anchor tag onclick() and href execute simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250645/html-anchor-tag-onclick-and-href-execute-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the context `this` , otherwise inside the function `this` will refer to the `window`

Also a button inside an anchor tag is not a valid HTML.`button` cannot be nested inside `a` tag.Check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5) for more information

```js
var tempscore = 0;
var currentscore = 0;

function categoryOnClick(elem) {
  console.log(elem)
  tempscore = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
  console.log(tempscore)
}
```

```html
<a href="Easy.html">
  <button type="button" onclick="categoryOnClick(this) " id="answer0" class="buttonquestion">200</button>
</a>
```