# jQuery show function

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
 <scrpit>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#viewDetails").on('click', function(){
                $('#content').show(2000);
            });     
        });
</script>
```

This is the navbar link and the id present in it

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="viewSchedule.php" class="nav-link" id="viewDetails">Trainings</a></li><div id="content">/*body I needed*/</div>
```

In this div tag, all the body of the page is present. This is the jQuery code I've tried but it didn't work. In the following image "Training" is the link to click and when I click the body should show in 3sec. By using PHP I imported the navbar using require once function. I checked in browser inspection but It's working fine and the script was not working and I even tried with an alert window that also working fine but I'm not getting the result

Here is the image that shows my page where the link is present

[image: [1]:]

Comment: In your code is `<scrpit>` a copy error or is it incorrect in the original code?

Comment: referred code @NigelRen

Comment: Sorry - not sure what that means.

Comment: I referred in a number of websites and came to that code

Comment: Do you think it should be `<script>`?

Comment: Do you actually need "href="viewSchedule.php"". If you click, then the call would go this page without seeing what the script did, right ?

Comment: yeah, when I click `href=viewSchedule.php` then my script has to run and give me that show animation @MukeshKeshu

Comment: I think the problem is that you have viewSchedule.php in the href attribute and when the user clicks on the menu item the browser follows the link. You can prevent this behavior (following the link) with `Event.preventDefault()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: sorry I didn't get you Mr. @András

Comment: The page will be redirected before the content becomes visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `href` associated with `<a>`. So when you click on it, that page gets loaded before the content is shown.First change `<scrpit>` to `<script>`. Then remove `href` attribute and add `hidden` to `id="content"` to make it hidden on load. See below -

```
<li class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" id="viewDetails">Trainings</a></li><div id="content" hidden>/*body I needed*/</div>
```

[See demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/h6mr3L52/4/)

Comment: Is there any CSS to add?

Comment: The functionality will work without any css. Add your own css if you need some styling.

Comment: As you said to remove `href` then how could I get my page without link?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346043/html-anchor-link-href-and-onclick-both

Comment: ThankYou Mr. Mukesh I tried everything but it's not working for me, thank you for your valuable time. If you have time can we get personal taking there I can explain to you my problem clearly `Email: gollapudi.smiles@gmail.com`

Comment: Mukesh Bro pls contact me: +91 7032285906

Answer (score 1):

You miss spelled "Script" in your code.

[image]

It should be `"<script>"`