# How to fix Links are not crawlable in my hugo social share partial

Tags: hugo

so i tested my website on lighthouse and i got this error does anyone knows how to fix it

> erro :Links are not crawlable

Uncrawlable Links on my partial

```
<a class="floating-header-share-tw" aria-label="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/share?text=5%20%d8%a3%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b1%20%d8%aa%d8%ac…" onclick="window.open(this.href,'share-twitter','width=550,height=235');return false;">
Linkedin

<a class="floating-header-share-in" aria-label="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=5%20%d8%a3%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b1%20…" onclick="window.open(this.href,'share-facebook','width=580,height=296');return fals…">
Facebook

<a class="floating-header-share-fb" aria-label="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3a%2f%2fmofeed.netlify.…" onclick="window.open(this.href,'share-facebook','width=580,height=296');return fals…">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are disabling the native functionality of the link with `return false`, as [previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346043/html-anchor-link-href-and-onclick-both).

Additionally:

1. You probably don't want those links crawled anyway so you should consider adding `rel=nofollow`
2. The aria-label attribute should be removed as you link has visible anchor text, it is just adding noise, potentially causing annoyance to screen-reader users who will hear the aria label and the link text both read out.

Comment: Hi thank's for tour answer, i have removed return false and replaced it with rel nofollow but the issue still exist